# Error in Calling python module from Java

Tags: java, python, jython-2.7

Java Code to call Python:

```
//arguments to be passed to the script
String[] patchArguments = { patchFileDirectory,centralPatchStagePath,patchId,patchFileName, action };
//initialize the interpreter with properties and arguments
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), System.getProperties(), patchArguments);
pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
//invoke python interpreter to execute the script
pythonInterpreter.execfile(opatchScriptPath + opatchScript);
```

Traceback (innermost last):

> File "/scratch/app/product/fmw/obpinstall/patching/scripts/PatchUtility.py", line 4, in ?
>
> ImportError: no module named subprocess

But subprocess is already installed and it runs if I execute the python file directly using terminal `python PatchUtility.py`

Update: I found something

> Jython has some limitations:
>
> There are a number of differences. First, Jython programs cannot use CPython
> extension modules written in C. These modules usually have files with the
> extension .so, .pyd or .dll.

does subprocess internally calls C-extensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No. Or Maybe. Or Yes. **But most relevant for you, in Jython, No.**

TLDR: Jython has its own implementation of subprocess

The details are a little sketchy on the python documentation, However the PEP has more details ( https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/ ). What this is is the specification for how it should work, not the actual implementation: An implemention of Python can do whatever it likes as long as its functionally the same (which ok, makes it not 'whatever' it likes but ... you get the idea).

From the spec:

> - On POSIX platforms, no extension module is required: the module
>        uses os.fork(), os.execvp() etc.
> - On Windows platforms, the module requires either Mark Hammond's
>        Windows extensions[5], or a small extension module called
>        _subprocess.

The Subprocess PEP aimed to prevent wierdnesses that were happening with using the `os.popen` type functions, however I also note on the Jython docs that this is implemented for jython, both os.fork and the entire subprocess module in its own right: http://www.jython.org/docs/library/subprocess.html

I suspect you have another bug somewhere, and perhaps an import error which makes it look like its subprocess which is failing to import.

The C-modules that you refer to is more about custom python c modules. These don't work as they bind against the python functions, where as jython implements its internals using Java bits. All core functions provided by the language have to have been ported to Java for the java interactions to work.